# the pathname-directory behave strange

Tags: directory, common-lisp, sbcl, pathname

I use SBCL 1.1.4, and found pathname-directory behave strange:

Say that there is a pathname contains "..", the following examples are trival.  SBCL converts every ".." to ":UP"

```
(pathname-directory "a/b/../")
(:RELATIVE "a" "b" :UP)

(pathname-directory "a/../b/../")
(:RELATIVE "a" :UP "b" :UP)
```

The problem comes here:

```
(pathname-directory "C:/test/../")
;;=> (:ABSOLUTE "test" :UP)

(truename "C:/test/..")
#P"C:/test/../"

(pathname-directory (truename "C:/test/.."))
;;=> (:ABSOLUTE "test" "..")

(pathname-directory #P"C:/test/../")
;;=> (:ABSOLUTE "test" :UP)
```

When call the pathname-directory on the return value of truename, the ".." is not converted to ":UP". The (truename "C:/test/..") also return #P"C:/test/../", so why the ".." is not converted?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with SBCL on Windows. The truename of `/a/b/..` should be `/a/`. Instead, it seems to return a reference to the `..` entry itself.

On Linux, this is what you get:

```
(truename "/etc/udev/..")
#P"/etc/"
```

I'd report this as a bug to the SBCL developers.

Comment: Could try try to run `(truename "c:/test/../")` as well? Without the final slash you are technically referring to a file named `..`, not a directory, so it could be argued that the behaviour is undefined.